# JavaScript: Simple Perceptron fails to train

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, neural-network, perceptron

I tried to make simple perceptron for predicting true or false, where 1 means true and false means -1.
but my perceptron fails to train itself and instead gives random values.

this is my class perceptron:

```js
function f(x){
    //number is in negative it returns -1
    if(x<0){
        return -1
    //number is in positive it returns 1
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}

class Perceptron{
    constructor(){
        //two weights
        this.weights = new Array(2)
        //intitializing two random weights
        for(let i = 0; i<this.weights.length; i++){
            this.weights[i] = Math.random()*2-1
        }
    }
    //prediction
    guess(input){
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i<input.length; i++){
           sum += this.weights[i]*input[i]//sum of all product of inputs and weights 
        }
        return f(sum)//returns -1 or 1
    }
    //training data
    train(inputs, target){
        this.lr = 0.1//learning rate
        let guess = this.guess(inputs)//answer comes either 1 or -1
        let err = target - guess//calc error
        for(let i = 0; i<this.weights.length; i++){
            this.weights[i] += err * inputs[i] * this.lr// re adjust the weights
        }
    }
}

export default Perceptron;
```

This is my main js:

```js
import Perceptron from "./perceptron.js"
const brain = new Perceptron;

let data = [{
    inputx: 1,
    inputy: 1,
    target: 1
},
{
    inputx: 0,
    inputy: 1,
    target: -1
},
{
    inputx: 1,
    inputy: 0,
    target: -1
},
{
    inputx: 0,
    inputy: 0,
    target: -1
}
]
for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    let inputs = [data[i].inputx, data[i].inputy]
    brain.train(inputs, data[i].target)
    let guess = brain.guess([1, 0])
    console.log(guess)
}
```

the perceptron does not predict exact data, instead gives random answers. What am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code in a snippet, so you can run it here.

```js
function f(x) {
  //number is in negative it returns -1
  if (x < 0) {
    return -1
    //number is in positive it returns 1
  } else {
    return 1
  }
}

class Perceptron {
  constructor() {
    //two weights
    this.weights = new Array(2)
    //intitializing two random weights
    for (let i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1
    }
  }

  //prediction
  guess(input) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      sum += this.weights[i] * input[i] //sum of all product of inputs and weights 
    }
    return f(sum) //returns -1 or 1
  }

  //training data
  train(inputs, target) {
    this.lr = 0.1 //learning rate
    const guess = this.guess(inputs) //answer comes either 1 or -1
    const err = target - guess //calc error
    for (let i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] += err * inputs[i] * this.lr // re adjust the weights
    }
  }
}

const brain = new Perceptron;

let data = [{
    inputx: 1,
    inputy: 1,
    target: 1
  },
  {
    inputx: 0,
    inputy: 1,
    target: -1
  },
  {
    inputx: 1,
    inputy: 0,
    target: -1
  },
  {
    inputx: 0,
    inputy: 0,
    target: -1
  }
]
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let inputs = [data[i].inputx, data[i].inputy]
  brain.train(inputs, data[i].target)
  let guess = brain.guess([1, 0])
  console.log(guess)
}
```

From the code what I see:

1. `Perceptron` initialised with random weights - OK
2. `Perceptron` fed with data - OK

If you analyse the guessing function, then you'll see some problems:

- `guess[1, 1]`: the weights are added up. Likely that their sum is 0+, so the guess will yield a correct answer most of the time
- `guess[0, 1]` and `guess[1, 0]`: only the weight that's paired with the `1` is taken into account (the other is multiplied by 0, then added to the sum); there's a slightly larger chance to yield a `1` than a `-1` (that means false guess), but mostly random
- `guess[0, 0]` is going to be always `false`, as it's internal sum (in the `guess` function) is going to be always 0, therefore yield a `1` from `f(x)` -> target is `-1` (false result)

The **Perceptron** works - as it modifies the weights during "learning", but is not going to yield significantly different answers than a random guess would.

### MODIFIED GUESS FUNCTION

```js
function f(x) {
  //number is in negative it returns -1
  if (x < 0) {
    return -1
    //number is in positive it returns 1
  } else {
    return 1
  }
}

class Perceptron {
  constructor() {
    //two weights
    this.weights = new Array(2)
    //intitializing two random weights
    for (let i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1
    }
  }

  //prediction
  guess(input) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      // -----------------------
      // changed the * to + here
      // -----------------------
      sum += this.weights[i] + input[i] //sum of all product of inputs and weights 
    }
    return f(sum) //returns -1 or 1
  }

  //training data
  train(inputs, target) {
    this.lr = 0.1 //learning rate
    const guess = this.guess(inputs) //answer comes either 1 or -1
    const err = target - guess //calc error
    for (let i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] += err * inputs[i] * this.lr // re adjust the weights
    }
  }
}

const brain = new Perceptron;

let data = [{
    inputx: 1,
    inputy: 1,
    target: 1
  },
  {
    inputx: 0,
    inputy: 1,
    target: -1
  },
  {
    inputx: 1,
    inputy: 0,
    target: -1
  },
  {
    inputx: 0,
    inputy: 0,
    target: -1
  }
]
for (let j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let inputs = [data[i].inputx, data[i].inputy]
    brain.train(inputs, data[i].target)
  }
}

let guess = 0
console.log('After 1 round of training:')
guess = brain.guess([1, 1])
console.log(guess)
guess = brain.guess([0, 1])
console.log(guess)
guess = brain.guess([1, 0])
console.log(guess)
guess = brain.guess([0, 0])
console.log(guess)
console.log('Weights:', brain.weights)

for (let j = 0; j < 999; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let inputs = [data[i].inputx, data[i].inputy]
    brain.train(inputs, data[i].target)
  }
}

console.log('After 1000 round of training:')
guess = brain.guess([1, 1])
console.log(guess)
guess = brain.guess([0, 1])
console.log(guess)
guess = brain.guess([1, 0])
console.log(guess)
guess = brain.guess([0, 0])
console.log(guess)
console.log('Weights:', brain.weights)
```

I changed the guess function

```
// from this:
sum += this.weights[i] * input[i]
// to this
sum += this.weights[i] + input[i]
```

and added some more rounds of training. I think the results speak for themselves (run it a couple of times to see the difference in 1 round of training vs. 1000 rounds of training).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the good explanation, i am 15 yr old, i want to make AIs in future this would help me alot for my future, thank you so much

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial I think this is a very good direction - you could try [BrainJS](https://brain.js.org/#/) or just simply look at some good Youtube videos, like [3Blue1Brown - Neural networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk&list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi). I'm glad that I could help!

Comment: yes i will use brain js in future but i actually want to make my own neural network so i can get better concept of it.